# Can a thread own other handles?

Tags: c#, windows

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx

> Executes the specified delegate on the thread that owns the control's
>   underlying window handle.

According to the MSDN article, a `thread` can own other handles.

My best guess, is that the `thread` is some special super `kernel object`, with a `handle` that other `handles` can refer too?

like:

> Handle | Thread-Handle-Reference
>
> 3201 | 20
>
> 4882 | 20
>
> 4827 | 7

Comment: What's the question exactly? If a custom thread can own other e.g. a window handle?

Comment: managed threads doesnt necessarily map directly to OS threads, it depends on the host, i think .net CLR host manages it differently than sql server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In these terms, yes.

Basically, behind the scenes of the Windows GUI is a "message loop", which is a two-way communication between the Windows OS (which knows about the mouse, keyboard and other input hardware) and your program (which doesn't need to know the specifics, but does need to be responsive to user input within your app based on these input devices). There is a thread in your program (the main program execution thread, usually) that maintains this loop, listening for messages coming into the program from Windows, and parsing and passing messages to the various GUI controls and other code objects. This "GUI messaging thread" knows and maintains references to all the window handles of all GUI objects in your program; it must, because if it doesn't, it cannot pass messages to them and will not be listening for messages from them.

It is generally a bad idea to try to do something to a GUI control instance from outside the thread that is connected to the message loop. By doing so, it is possible for the control or sub-controls owned by the control to become detached from the message loop, or to never be attached in the first place. The "GUI message thread" then no longer knows about that control, and is no longer passing messages to or from it. Those controls become "rogue"; neither the program nor Windows can tell the control to move, redraw itself, or go away. The only thing Windows can do at that point to "control" the window is to shut down the process that owns it, thus terminating your entire program.

To avoid this, GUI controls have a special method "Invoke" (and an asynchronous cousin "BeginInvoke") designed to be used from outside the GUI messaging thread. These methods basically send a message from the window to itself through the Windows message loop that causes the main GUI thread to execute the delegate specified in the Invoke call. By doing so, any new GUI objects created within or as a result of that code will be known to the main GUI thread.

Comment: Wow! - That sure cleared a lot of things up - thanks! - Is `main program execution thread`, and `GUI messaging thread` the same thread?

Comment: Almost always. It is possible to attach a different thread to a Windows message loop, but it is very rarely done. It can be useful, but you have to be REALLY careful.

Comment: @KeithS: I think that ebb was asking if it was possible to create windows from threads other than the main thread of the app.  That's very straightforward to do (although you need to be careful that main() doesn't return until after the window thread is shut down).

Comment: Yes, you can create a form, or any other control you can think of, in a different thread. That makes the thread that created the control a GUI thread, and a message pump will be created for that thread when the first GDI call is made by the thread. However, ownership of a handle and ownership of a form object in code are two very different things, and one does not imply the other. If a background thread creates a new control, that thread must continue to run as long as the control exists, or it will go "rogue" when the thread stops. Background threads are usually short-lived and single-purpose

Comment: Additionally, although a form may have a particular control in its child control tree, if the control was created by another thread, the form's thread may not act on the control directly (you'll cause a "cross-threading exception"); it must call Invoke on that control every time code that changes the state of the control must be run.

Answer (score 1):

A custom thread can own handles when the handle is created in the custom thread. Actually i don't think that you can switch the owner of the handle. Sharing should be not possible too.

A thread can own multiple handles at once.

Answer (score 0):

Every window is owned by the thread which created the window.  Many window operations can only be performed on that thread, so it's important to have a mechanism to ensure that code is executed on the window's thread.

Forms.Invoke is one such mechanism.